# push log from logstash-forwarder to logstash

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

I am not able to push log from logstash-forwarder to logstash
here my logstash-forwarder.conf

```
{ "network":{
 "servers": [ "logstash_server_private_address:5000" ],
    "timeout": 15,
    "ssl ca": "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
},
"files":[

{
      "paths": [
        "/var/log/syslog",
        "/var/log/auth.log"
       ],
      "fields": { "type": "syslog" }
    }
]
}
```

while running following command

```
$ /opt/logstash-forwarder/bin/logstash-forwarder -config /etc/↩
logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder.conf
```

I am getting following exception...

```
Failed unmarshalling json: invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value.  Could not load config file /etc/NetworkManager invalid character '\x00' looking for beginning of value
```

Comment: Interesting character after "/etc/" in your command line...

Comment: Can you mark this question as answered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it is working :-

```
bin/logstash-forwarder -config /etc/logstash-forwarder.conf
```